# Grab Value from Javascript popup - use as php post value

Tags: php, javascript, html, webforms

First off, if there is a completely better way of doing this? let me know...  This way seems kind of "hackish".  Here is what I am trying to do:  As you see in the below `input`, I have a text field that I simple want to appear like an `<a>` link.  If the user clicks it, I want `JavaScript` pop up box to appear with user entering the email.  I want them to hit ok, and I send that email value back to the form and the form then submits via a php post.

I do not know how to grab the value from the box and insert it in the `form` (if possible) so it can submit to `php`.

Here is the code:

```
    <form id="frm1" action="login.php" method = "post">
        <input onclick="resetPassword()" type="text" name="email" value="Reset Password" style="cursor: pointer; background:none; text-decoration: underline; border: none;"  />
    </form>


    <script>
        function resetPassword() {
        var x;

        var email=prompt("Enter email to reset password.", "example@email.com");

        if (email!=null)
          {
          document.getElementById("frm1").submit();
          }
        }
   </script>


  <?php 
     if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
         $email = $database -> escape_value(trim($_POST['email']));
        //  reset password    
      }
  ?>
```

Comment: You can use either jquery event post() or javascript post method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit or http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: are you sending the data ..i dont see the code here

Comment: In the php part I email the new password to the user; I cut that out because that is after the fact.  I simple need to send the users current email address TO php first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab the email from promt, paste it to input field and submit the form.

```
<form id="frm1" action="login.php" method='post'>
    <input id="email" onclick="resetPassword()" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Reset Password" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function resetPassword() {    
    var email = prompt("Enter email to reset password.", "email@example.com");

    if (email != null) {
      document.getElementById("email").value = email; 
      document.getElementById("frm1").submit();
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Edit:  Ok, the email IS being set, but when I get to php it is a blank value.

Comment: I assume the edit only was `method='post'`?  I already had that actually cause I noticed earlier it was missing.  everything else looks identical...  exept I have inline CSS and a `readonly` in the form

Comment: `document.getElementById("email").val = email` was changed to `document.getElementById("email").value = email`

Answer (score 1):

Add an ID to the `input` field:

```
<form id="frm1" action="login.php">
    <input id="email" onclick="resetPassword()" type="text" name="email" value="Reset Password" style="cursor: pointer; background:none; text-decoration: underline; border: none;"  />
</form>

    function resetPassword() {

    var email=prompt("Enter email to reset password.", "example@email.com");

    if (email!=null)
      {
      document.getElementById("email").value = email; // Put value into form field
      document.getElementById("frm1").submit();
      }
    }
```

If you don't want the user to be able to type directly into the form field, you should give it the `readonly` attribute. `onclick` prevents them from clicking on it, but they could still get there with <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: Great catch on `readonly`.  Though the other code still isn't pasting it over.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `.value` (I usually use jQuery, which has `.val()` for the analogous operation).

Comment: Yup, the other guy figured that one out too.  I could have marked you both correct, but had to pick one... thanks for your incite on this.  The least I can do it upvote the answer!

Answer (score 1):

A better aproach would be the use of jQuery and send the info of the text field via AJAX to the script which is expecting the $_POST variable. This way, the `<form>` element would be unnecessary.

```
    function resetPassword() {
        var x;
        var email=prompt("Enter email to reset password.", "example@email.com");
        if (email!=null) {
             $.post( url_of_the_script, {email: email}, function() { alert('Email sent'); } );
        }
    }
```